# Wiping out data in Calendar and People?

Tags: calendar, people-app

I'd like to test the different solutions available to sync Outlook with Androphones through USB.

To start from a clean state, is there a way to wipe out the contents of Calendar and People, so I don't have to delete each item manually between each try?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Settings, Applications then find the All tab. Scroll down and you will find Calendar Storage and Contact Data. Open each of these and choose clear data.